# I am facing some problems when running the ng-Serve

Tags: angular

WARNING in ./node_modules/@coreui/angular/fesm5/coreui-angular.js
865:166-174 "export 'ɵɵinject' was not found in '@angular/core'

Comment: Once delete node_modules folder and then run npm install.